# Add field to a confirmation block message

Tags: adminhtml, blocks, forms

I need to add a field in my confirmation message in the block.

I have my class here

```
class Ismo_Myclass_Model_Observer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $order = $block->getOrder();
            if($order->hasShipments()){
                $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to regenerate the stickers and resend the new tracking number to customer?');
                $block->addButton('order_Sticker_bouton', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Sticker'),
                    'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getPrintStickerUrl($order)}')",
                ));   
            }
        }  

    }
```

[image]

I need to add a field like this

```
$block->addField('nb_sticker', 'text', array(
                    'name'      => 'nb_sticker',
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('nb sticker'),
                    'title'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('nb sticker'),
                    'required'  => true,
                ));
```

but in the confirmation popup

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do it with confirmation box.**

```
'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getPrintStickerUrl($order)}')",
```

This `confirmSetLocation` function basically just popup the confirmation java-script alert.

You can find that in tools.js

```
function confirmSetLocation(message, url){
    if( confirm(message) ) {
        setLocation(url);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to add field in that you will need to use **prompt**. For that you will need to create your own function like confirmSetLocation for prompt. See the java-script example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt).

[image]

Comment: Hi Patel, thanks for your help, but I am very confusing because I am not able to find the script with this function confirmSetLocation, nor to find the script tool.js.  Where have I to find this function?

Comment: edited my answer with image.

Comment: Hi Patel, I replace confirmSetLocation by printStickerNumber, and I have 'onclick'   => "printStickerNumber('{$this->getPrintStickerUrl($order)}')", in the php file. and in tool.js, i have function printStickerNumber() {
    var numberSticker = prompt("Please enter the number of sticker you need or put blank for calculation", "");
    return numberSticker;
},   but how can I have the value numberSticker for my function function getPrintStickerUrl($order) ?

Comment: I think you will be need to call Ajax and pass your 'numberSticker' in post. you can use that in your Ajax action can do further process as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Patel, the frontend is not to much my stuff. can you show me an example or tutorial which can help me to understand. thanks